# amp-live-list fails validation

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I am trying to use the `<amp-live-list>` component but I get this error in the console :

> The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.

I already have this list of scripts on my page with no errors :

```
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-twitter" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-twitter-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-youtube" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-youtube-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-instagram" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-instagram-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-pinterest" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-pinterest-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-soundcloud" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-soundcloud-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-vimeo" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-vimeo-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-vine" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-vine-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-user-notification" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-user-notification-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
```

BUT it fails when I add the script for `<amp-live-list>` :

```
<script async custom-element="amp-live-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-live-list-0.1.js"></script>
```

Since this component is still in experimental mode, I have tried this :

```
AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-live-list');
```

With no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [AMP Experimental Components Page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/experimental.html):

> Any AMP file that includes experimental features will fail AMP validation. Remove these experimental components for production-ready AMP documents.

So regardless of whether or not you have `AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-live-list');`, the validator will fire an error if you include the script for `<amp-live-list>`.